# Where to check for Android Permissions?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

We are moving our app to SDK 23 and realize that we need to explicitly handle permissions in the code.

Instead of going through the entire code base, is there a best practice (or an IDE shortcut) that would help us determine all the places where we may need to use 'ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission' for each permission in the app?

Comment: It would be nice if there were lint checks for all the different required permission checks but unless it changed recently the are only a few lint checks for where you need to check permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio try this:

1- Click on Hector the Inspector (the small icon of a man with a moustache at the very bottom-right of Android Studio). This will show up an option to Configure inspections.

2- Type 'Permissions' into the searchbar, and ensure that "Constant and Resource Type Mismatches" is checked.

3- Run Analyse > Inspect Code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for permission each time you use the functionnality who requires it, because you do not know witch path the user will follow in your app.

Remove all permissions node in Manifest, test your app and identify every time you get  a permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio 2.2 a new feature is implemented to make it easier to move your app to SDK 23. It is still work in progress howerver.

It is shown [here](https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?t=21m35s). It adds an option to the refactor menu, which automatically implements the necessary permission checks.